# MongoDB is it a good idea to use _id as entity ID

Tags: mongodb, primary-key

Porting a relational table structure to Mongo Collection, wondering whether we can use the _id as the primary Key for the collection, similar as we use entity ID, If yes is there a way other than in code that we can do aliasing for this property while doing a find.

Thanks,
-V

Answer (score 1):

Here it is a good start from you documentation. And yes you can do "relational collections"

**[Relational Databases to Mongo](http://blog.mongodb.org/post/72874267152/transitioning-from-relational-databases-to-mongodb)**

and

**[Transitioning from Relational Databases to MongoDB - Data Models](http://code.tutsplus.com/articles/mapping-relational-databases-and-sql-to-mongodb--net-35650)**

Hope if helps you.